# Android simulator into landscape

Tags: android-emulator

I haven't figured out how to put the `Android emulator` into `landscape`. I want to test the `landscape` design of a `layout`, but how should that be done ?

Answer (score 6):

For short cut once your `emulator` start click `CTRL F11` and for reverse also you can do the same and you can test in both mode .